# how to replace multi new line with single new line in Xcode using Find & Replace

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

In Xcode projects, we generally write programs without paying attention to line spacing.

So after coding is complete, how does one remove all those extra newlines with single line?

Answer (score 16):

In the textual search field... one can do multiline / "non-printing character" search / replace by use of the following methods...

Say I wanted to replace all instances of

```
/**
 * This is a comment...
```

with

```
/**  This is a comment...
```

The "search term" would be entered as...

`/**`<kbd>Alt/Option + Enter</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>`*`<kbd>Space</kbd>

and the replace term would be entered simply as...

`/**`<kbd>Alt/Option + Tab</kbd>

The moral of the story..  when you want to use characters that serve alternate purposes within the Search / Replace fields... combine the modifier <kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> with their entry to use them "literally".

Answer (score 12):

XCode's find and replace does not support multi-line regular expressions.

If you want to search for multiple lines you'll need to set your search option to "Textual" and either type option+return twice or copy/paste in two new lines chars.  Then replace with a single new line char.

See [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/279310-multiline-regexp-in-the-xcode.html) for more information.

Comment: copy and paste newlines from an open XCode editor into the replace field is the only thing I've found that works.  Best solution is to use AppCode... hugely more feature rich interface than XCode.

Comment: This answer is wrong / outdated. Xcode does support multi-line regular expressions.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by using a temporary string in its place. My problem was a little different, I wanted to find anywhere I had no blank line between a property and method declaration in an interface, like this:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSBlah *someThing;
- (id)someMethodThing;
```

And replace with:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSBlah *someThing;

- (id)someMethodThing;
```

In order to do this, I used this to find using multi-line:

```
@property(.*)\n([-+].*)
```

Then I replaced that with some text string in place of the newlines:

```
@property$1SOMETHINGWHATEVER123$2
```

Then, I switched off regex replace, and with regular text replace, replaced:

```
SOMETHINGWHATEVER123
```

With Xcode's newline character, which you can find by choosing Insert Pattern by clicking the magnifying glass (this is in Xcode 7):

[image]

This then replaces that `SOMETHINGWHATEVER123` with two newlines, resulting in my multiline regex query being handled.

Not sure how directly applicable this is to your circumstances, given that this is so old, but I found my way here, so perhaps others might!

Answer (score 2):

Modern Xcode (writing as of Xcode 11) DOES support multi-line regular expressions. Just add `(?s)` modifier before `.` to perform this type of search, e.g.:

`Codable(?s).*rawValue` will search for text blocks starting with `Codable` ending with `rawValue` regardless of how many lines they span.